# input dimensions to a one dimensional convolutional network in keras

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, conv-neural-network, keras

really finding it hard to understand the input dimensions to the convolutional 1d [layer](http://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#convolution1d) in keras:

Input shape

3D tensor with shape: (samples, steps, input_dim).

Output shape

3D tensor with shape: (samples, new_steps, nb_filter). steps value might have changed due to padding.

I want my network to take in a time series of prices (101, in order) and output 4 probabilities. My current non-convolutional network which does this fairly well (with a training set of 28000) looks like this:

```
standardModel = Sequential()
standardModel.add(Dense(input_dim=101, output_dim=100, W_regularizer=l2(0.5), activation='sigmoid'))
standardModel.add(Dense(4, W_regularizer=l2(0.7), activation='softmax'))
```

To improve this, I want to make a feature map from the input layer which has a local receptive field of length 10. (and therefore has 10 shared weights and 1 shared bias). I then want to use max pooling and feed this in to a hidden layer of 40 or so neurons and then output this with 4 neurons with softmax in the outer layer.

[picture (it's quite awful sorry!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx8yT.png)

So ideally, the convolutional layer would take a 2d tensor of dimensions:

(minibatch_size, 101)

and output a 3d tensor of dimensions

(minibatch_size, 91, no_of_featuremaps)

However, the keras layer seems to require a dimension in the input called step. I've tried understanding this and still don't quite get it. In my case, should step be 1 as each step in the vector is an increase in the time by 1? Also, what is new_step?

In addition, how do you turn the output of the pooling layers (a 3d tensor) into input suitable for the standard hidden layer (i.e a Dense keras layer) in the form of a 2d tensor?

Update: After the very helpful suggestions given, I tried making a convolutional network like so:

```
conv = Sequential()
conv.add(Convolution1D(64, 10, input_shape=(1,101)))
conv.add(Activation('relu'))
conv.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
conv.add(Flatten())
conv.add(Dense(10))
conv.add(Activation('tanh'))
conv.add(Dense(4))
conv.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

The line conv.Add(Flatten()) throws a range exceeds valid bounds error. Interestingly, this error is **not** thrown for just this code:

```
conv = Sequential()
conv.add(Convolution1D(64, 10, input_shape=(1,101)))
conv.add(Activation('relu'))
conv.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
conv.add(Flatten())
```

doing

```
print conv.input_shape
print conv.output_shape
```

results in

```
(None, 1, 101
(None, -256)
```

being returned

Update 2:

Changed

```
conv.add(Convolution1D(64, 10, input_shape=(1,101)))
```

to

```
conv.add(Convolution1D(10, 10, input_shape=(101,1))
```

and it started working. However, is there any important different between 
inputting (None, 101, 1) to a 1d conv layer or (None, 1, 101) that I should be aware of? Why does (None, 1, 101) not work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason why it look like this is that Keras designer intended to make 1-dimensional convolutional framework to be interpreted as a framework to deal with sequences. To fully understand the difference - try to imagine that you have a sequence of a multiple feature vectors. Then your output will be at least two dimensional - where first dimension is connected with time and other dimensions are connected with features. 1-dimensional convolutional framework was designed to in some way bold this time dimension and try to find the reoccuring patterns in data - rather than performing a classical multidimensional convolutional transformation.

In your case you must simply reshape your data to have shape (dataset_size, 101, 1) - because you have only one feature. It could be easly done using `numpy.reshape` function. To understand what does a new step mean - you must understand that you are doing the convolution over time - so you change the temporal structure of your data - which lead to new time-connected structure. In order to get your data to a format which is suitable for dense / static layers use `keras.layers.flatten` layer - the same as in classic convolutional case.

**UPDATE:** As I mentioned before - the first dimension of input is connected with time. So the difference between `(1, 101)` and `(101, 1)` lies in that in first case you have one time step with 101 features and in second - 101 timesteps with 1 feature. The problem which you mentioned after your first change has its origin in making pooling with size 2 on such input. Having only one timestep - you cannot pool any value on a time window of size 2 - simply because there is not enough timesteps to do that.

Comment: ah ok I sort of see. So if my data was not just price against time, but price, rainfall and market volume per time, i would give the first layer something of dimensions (sample_size, 101, 3)?

Comment: I also tried doing something similar to this just now, and the flatten layer is throwing a strange error (some sort of overflow?)